# How can I make xargs play nice with stdin?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, xargs

```
$ seq 1 3
1
2
3
$ seq 1 3 | xargs echo
1 2 3
$
```

Mentally replace `seq 1 3` with any command that lists entries one-per-line on standard out.  How can I get more-or-less what you'd expect, i.e. the entries on separate lines (`echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;`)?

Comment: Often is `xargs` not the command you need. You are using two external commands `seq` respectively `xargs` to achieve something that your shell can do it on it's own. Take for example Brace expansion in bash. You could then issue `printf '%s\n' {1..10}`  to get the desired result

Comment: @val0x00ff My real use case is implementing a [`Brewfile` for homebrew](https://github.com/vermiculus/dotfiles/blob/mac/Brewfile) in [my own bootstrap script](https://github.com/vermiculus/dotfiles/blob/mac/bootstrap#L17). I'm not sure I can use any features of the shell to do the job.

Comment: The function you have there `nocomment` and `oneline` could be combined into one function `nocomment_oneline`  and put `sed '/^#/d;/^.$/d' "$1"  | sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n/ /;ta'`

Comment: @val0x00ff Yes, but then I couldn't actually *use* it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't be able to? That just combines both functions. You are using one function to filter out comments and empty lines. After that you are reading the file and putting all lines in one.

Comment: @val0x00ff Read more carefully – I use `nocomment` for the Homebrew stuff – `brew` can't take multiple kinds of commands.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. The behavior that you describe is exactly what I'd expect from this command. The job of `xargs` is to read a list of items from its standard input, in a syntax that no tool produces, and invoke a command on those items in bulk. Your example is a straightforward use of `xargs`. This may well not be what you want. But then what do you want?

Comment: @Gilles It wasn't what I had expected from my previous use of `xargs` (which I may have just aliased to `xargs -n 1` on my old machine). What I want is pretty simple: "How can I get […] the entries on separate lines?" i.e. `echo 1; echo 2; echo 3;`.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you want.

Comment: @Gilles Done :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally `xargs` will put several arguments on one command line.  To limit it to one argument at a time, use the `-n` option:

```
$ seq 3 | xargs -n 1 echo
1
2
3
```

#### Documentation

From `man xargs`:

> **-n max-args**
>                 Use  at  most  max-args  arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the
>                 size (see the -s option) is exceeded, unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.

#### Difference between `-n` and `-L`

`-L` is similar but has an extra feature:  unlike `-n`, lines with trailing blanks are continued onto the next line.  Observe:

```
$ echo $'1 \n2\n3\n4'
1 
2
3
4
$ echo $'1 \n2\n3\n4' | xargs -L 1 echo
1 2
3
4
$ echo $'1 \n2\n3\n4' | xargs -n 1 echo
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I wonder: how do `-n` and `-L` differ in terms of use-case? Surely they must differ outside of this trivial example.

Comment: @SeanAllred `-L` differs in that it has a  trailing blank feature.  I just added an example illustrating it. (Your answer has my +1)

Comment: I think Sean means, when would you use `xargs -L`? When is the trailing blanks feature useful?

Answer (score 6):

A bit more research revealed the answer from [Make xargs execute the command once for each line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199266/1443496):

```
$ seq 1 3 | xargs -L 1 echo
1
2
3
```